# how to save ListView items to a csv file

Tags: android, csv, listview

Each line of the ListView contains 5 strings separated by semi-colon as follows:

```
str1; str2; str3; str4; str5
```

The record length of the list can vary, which may sometimes reach up to 400

How can I save the list to a CSV file (in the internal storage of the device, application folder path)

Using ArrayAdapter:

```
private static MainActivity inst;
    ArrayList<String> inList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView myList;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dataList);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, inList);
        myList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
```

Sample data in ListView:

Shop1; orange; 10; 200;2000
Shop2;orange;8;150;1200
Shop3;lemon;20;100;2000

Comment: This is a very broad question. You could post a bit of your code samples for us to look at. However, to give you an idea, all the data present in the ListView must be present in an `Adapter`. I recommend you get all the data from the Adapter, split the content as `;` a separator, and then recreate a CSV by appending `,` as a separator. Finally, you can export this data to a file to get your CSV. With this approach, it is independent of the record length.

Comment: @@Atish, I included the ArrayAdapter script. can you put your idea that into code ?

Comment: I would need sample data too

Comment: @@Atish, please see the sample data I included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a sample activity for your reference.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ArrayList<String> listDataArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String line1 = "Shop1; orange; 10; 200;2000";
        String line2 = "Shop2;orange;8;150;1200";
        String line3 = "Shop3;lemon;20;100;2000";

        listDataArray = new ArrayList<>();

        listDataArray.add(line1);
        listDataArray.add(line2);
        listDataArray.add(line3);


        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listDataArray);
        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewData)).setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }


    public void processCSV(View view) {

        try {

            boolean writePermissionStatus = checkStoragePermission(false);
            //Check for permission
            if (!writePermissionStatus) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return;
            } else {
                boolean writePermissionStatusAgain = checkStoragePermission(true);
                if (!writePermissionStatusAgain) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    //Permission Granted. Export
                    exportDataToCSV();

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String toCSV(String[] array) {
        String result = "";
        if (array.length > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : array) {
                sb.append(s.trim()).append(",");
            }
            result = sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1).toString();
        }
        return result;
    }


    private void exportDataToCSV() throws IOException {


        String csvData = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < listDataArray.size(); i++) {

            String currentLIne = listDataArray.get(i);
            String[] cells = currentLIne.split(";");

            csvData += toCSV(cells) + "\n";

        }


        File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        String uniqueFileName = "FileName.csv";
        File file = new File(directory, uniqueFileName);
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        fileWriter.write(csvData);
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Exported Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    private boolean checkStoragePermission(boolean showNotification) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (showNotification) showNotificationAlertToAllowPermission();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    private void showNotificationAlertToAllowPermission() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Please allow Storage Read/Write permission for this app to function properly.").setPositiveButton("Open Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();

    }

}
```

**Explanation**

1. I have created 3 static `String` with the input as you provided.
2. I created an `ArrayList` adding all these 3 sample data. We would be assuming this `ArrayList` to be the data.
3. Created an `Adapter` same as you were trying to implement, and then added it to the `ListView` for displaying.
4. Created a `Button` **Export CSV** to export CSV to the external directory Downloads Folder.
5. Other helpful methods for permission checks and converters.

When the user clicks, **Export CSV**, the following process starts:

1. The first task is to check if the user has given permissions to export the CSV or not. If **No**, request for permission, otherwise, continue to `exportDataToCSV()` method.
2. In this function, Loop though all the rows (lines) in the `ArrayList` which you created to populate the listview (by setting in the adapter), and get the `currentLine`.
3. Split the contents using `;` as a separator and create a local String `Array`.
4. Pass this array to `toCSV` method, which joins the data with `,` as this will be used to create CSV (Comma Separated Values). Append a blank line `\n` at the end of each line to create rows.
5. Finally, once you have all the data in the String `csvData`, Write the output to a file.

Obviously, there could be more efficient ways of doing this, but I have separated each function as far as possible, to make it easy to understand.

The other way to generate CSV from the `currentLine`, could be to replace `;` with `,` directly. You should try that by yourself.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="processCSV"
        android:text="Export CSV" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @@Atish, from where do you call processCSV ?

Comment: That's a button click method from the View

Comment: As is now, nothing has happened. Then, I tried to call processCSV with getProcessCSV()  but no acction is passed to save the file

Comment: I wondered if some uses-permissions are missing in the Manifest

Comment: @Allen I have added my XML files for your reference. Yes, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is required to write files in external storage.

Comment: I have been testing this on Emulator and I couldn't locate the saved file in it. And no Toast message "File Exported Successfully" on button click to confirm if file is saved. By the way, you refer to external storage. In my question, I wanted the file to be stored in the device's internal storage, under this specific application path.  I there still something I missed in this process?

Comment: If there is no Toast message, it means there is some error. Did you try debugging the code? I too tried the code over emulator and it is working perfectly fine. Also, saving to internal or external storage is not the context of the question. Rather, it is to convert the ListView data to CSV. You can modify the export functions to suit your needs. If you still need help, please feel free to contact again.

Comment: all I use is Android 3.5.3 Gradle 5.4.1, Target SDK 29, min SDK 15.  I couldn't figure out why it is not saving the file

Comment: @@Atish, it did work on real device, excellent! Maybe are issues with the emulator I am using

Comment: That sounds great. Mark the answer as accepted so that the question can be closed.